# If $(f_n')$ converges uniformly on an interval, does $(f_n)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions that are all differentiable on an interval A, and suppose the sequence of derivatives $(f_n')$ [converges uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) on A to a limit function $g$. Does it follow that $(f_n)$ converges to a limit function f on A?

What I tried:

As $(f_n')$ converges uniformly to $g$, we may write that the limit of integral of $(f_n')$ is the integral of the limit of $(f_n')$. Hence, $(f_n)$ converges point wise to the integral of $g$.

How does this sound?

Comment: Not quite. Pick $f_n(x)=(-1)^n$. We need a bit more to exclude this type of counterexample. For example the convergence of $(f_n(a))$ for some fixed $a\in A$.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $f_n(x)=n$, then you always have $f_n'(x)=0$. Therefore, $(f_n')_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly, but there is no $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $\bigl(f_n(x)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges.

Answer (score 25):

*This   might help in your thinking about this.*

You have your simple counterexample so the real question is what extra assumption is needed so that your attempted proof would work?  It would be a failed student exercise to toss such questions out the window simply because a trivial counterexample dismisses them.

**Problem #1.**  As pointed out by *José* in his answer and *Severin* in his comment, you need to have some control over the primitive functions $f_n$.  The standard assumption usually added to make this work is that  $f_n(x_0)$ converges for at least one point $x_0$ in the interval $A$.

**Problem #2.**  That is an excellent idea to convert this to a statement about integrals and then use some integration theory to solve it for you. What integration theory would you like to use?

1. If each $f_n$ is continuously differentiable you can use the Riemann integral. Then $f_n'\to g$ uniformly etc.   Good.
2. If $f_n$ are all differentiable with each $f_n'$  Riemann integrable you can do the same.  Great.
3. If $f_n$ are all differentiable with $f_n'$ each Lebesgue integrable you can do the same.  Great yet again.
4. **But** (big but) what if $f_n$ are all differentiable with $f_n'$ **not** Lebesgue integrable.  You have any more integrals hiding in your closet?  (There are a few in mine but I am a collector of such esoterica.)

So the integration idea is shot down in general unless you want to prove a weak version by adding an extra hypothesis about the functions in the sequence $\{f_n\}$.

---

A proof of the most general version of your "derivatives converge uniformly" theorem can be found in the reference below.

See **Section 9.6.1 Limits of Discontinuous Derivatives,  Theorem 9.37:** in this
free PDF
http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Portrait.pdf

The assumptions are that $f_n:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ are differentiable, $f'_n\to g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ and $f_n(x_0)$ converges for some point.  Then $f_n$ converges uniformly to some differentiable function $f$ and $f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'(x).$

Before consulting consider trying for a proof (avoiding integrals as too special) and using instead everyone's favorite tool from your freshman calculus: the mean-value theorem.

---

**P.S.**   If you are reading this and confused about the fact that derivatives do not have to be integrable (Riemann or Lebesgue) then there is something more to learn here.